# C++: use of “().” and “()[].”

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the programming of Siemens scanner using C++ and given that my C++ skills are limited, I am having problems in understanding many parts of the code provided by the vendor.

### Problem 1

For instance, the code uses reference (rMrProt) to object MrProt and notations (such as the use of use of `().` and `()[].`) are very confusing to me.
For instance:

```
ImageSamples = rMrProt.kSpace().baseResolution()
ImageSize = rMrProt.sliceSeries()[0].readoutFOV()
```

Some explanation of these statements would be appreciated.

All information regarding object MrProt are in “MrProt.h”, “MrProt.dll”, “MrProt.lib”. All these files have been shared at:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0Ah9soYnrlIYWZkNDU2M2EtYTNmNC00YTc5LTllMzItYzIyMWU4M2ZhY2Fi

### Problem 2

Also, I have been trying to read MrProt.dll and MrProt.lib without any success. Only now, I came to know of dumpbin. Any help would be appreciated.

### Problem 3

Another confusion that I have is related to some part of MrProt.h itself. There is a statement in MrProt.h:

```
class __IMP_EXP MrProt: public MrProtocolData::MrProtDataDelegate
{
   typedef MrProtocolData::MrProtDataDelegate BasicImplementation;
   public:
   MrProt();
   MrProt(const MrProt& rSource);
   …
   ….
}
```

Here, `__IMP_EXP`, I guess that it’s some compiler specific stuff.. some decoration etc. But, I still have no idea what to make of this.

Comment: The document link is inaccessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem 1.

```
rMrProt.sliceSeries()[0].readoutFOV()
```

means

- Take `rMrProt`'s `sliceSeries` member and call that. Apparently, it returns an array-like object, something that can be indexed.
- From the result, take the first element (`[0]`). That's some kind of object.
- On that element/object, call `readoutFOV`.

Problem 2. You're not really supposed to read binary files. There should be documentation with them.

Comment: Superultramicropedanticism: you can't return an array

Comment: @SethCarnegie: true, called it an "array-like object". It's hard not to answer this with "go read a book on C++".

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes, that's why it was a superultramicropedanticism.

Comment: Can someone also explain the use of  __IMP_EXP as illustrated in problem 3?

Answer (score 3):

1)

```
ImageSamples = rMrProt.kSpace().baseResolution()
```

This is just method chaining. You call the method `kSpace()` on `rMrPrto` which returns an object, and you call `baseResolution()` on that object.

2) Those are binary files. What would you expect to see? To read them you'd have to be an expert in asm or at least know some low-level concepts.

3) `__IMP_EXP` is a common type of directive that tells the compiler that the class is either exported or imported.

It expands to `_declspec(dllimport)` or `_declspec(dllexport)`, depending on whether the definition of the class is in the current module or another module.

Answer (score 1):

identifier() is a method/function call

identifier[i] returns the i'th element in an array.

identifier()[i] returns the i'th element of the array returned by identifier()

Answer (score 1):

I can only help on problem 1:

if the return value of `rMrProt.kSpace()` is a struct. instead of saving it to a struct and then access it's member you can directly access a member of his with `rMrProt.kSpace().MemberName`

same for `rMrProt.sliceSeries()` which I guess is returning an array. so `rMrProt.sliceSeries()[0]` will access the first value in the returning array.